# How to migrate Mcrypt to openssl function to encrypt with PHP7.3

Tags: encryption, openssl, mcrypt, php-7.3

Unfortunately 7.3 doesn't support mcrypt and I have to refactor some code.
I cannot migrate this encription function:

```
mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, pkcs5_pad(trim($strToEncode), mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
```

I tried this code:

```
function pkcs5_pad ($text, $blocksize) 
{ 
   $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize); 
   return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad); 
} 

$cipher = "aes-128-gcm";
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher));
$block_size = strlen(openssl_encrypt('', $cipher, '', OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt(pkcs5_pad(trim($strToEncode),$block_size), $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv);
```

But it doesn't work and I got: Uncaught DivisionByZeroError in pkcs5_pad function

Comment: The main reason is obvious! The MCrypt uses ECB mode but you are trying to use AES-128-GCM in the new code. Also, AES-128-GCM internally uses CTR mode that does not require any padding.

Comment: In addition, the ECB-mode doesn't use an IV, but this happens in the mcrypt_encrypt-call, so that even the mcrypt_encrypt-call isn't consistent.

Comment: Sorry guys, for me is not obvious, I don't know encryption differences. I need to refactor this small part of a script that is not working anymore with php7.3 and mcrypt seems to be deprecated. Which cypher should I use in openssl to replace MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128?

Comment: In addition to the algorithm, an operation mode must be defined. In `mcrypt_encrypt`, AES-128 (`MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128`) is defined with 
ECB-mode (`MCRYPT_MODE_ECB`). In `openssl_encrypt` both are specified in a single parameter and this would be `aes-128-ecb`. However, it should 
be noted that the ECB-mode is _insecure_. Furthermore, the ECB-mode doesn't use an IV, i.e. the IV in `mcrypt_encrypt` is simply ignored.

Comment: Ok thanks I solved with `$cipher = "aes-128-ecb"; $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt(trim($strToEncode), $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the working code:

```
$cipher = "aes-128-ecb";
$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt(trim($strToEncode), $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
```